# Yahoo メールアプリからiOS アプリにDeeplink ができません

Tags: swift, ios, objective-c

#### 前提・実現したいこと

iOS アプリを開発しております。
ユーザ登録機能において、メールアドレス認証で、認証URL からアプリにDeeplink させる方式をとっているのですが、
Yahoo メール（@yahoo.co.jp） をYahoo メールクライアントアプリ（https://itunes.apple.com/jp/app/yahoo-%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB/id669931877?mt=8）
で開く際、クライアントアプリから外部アプリにDeeplink できない問題に直面しています。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

上記の認証URL から外部アプリにDeeplink させる方法として URL Scheme を使っています。
またyahoo メールのクライアントアプリは、URL をクライアントアプリ内のWebView で開く仕様となっており、
WebView 側でURL Scheme をハンドルできていないようです。

#### 該当のソースコード

以下のように、認証URL を開くと、Javascript でURL scheme を呼び出すページを用意しています。

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var fallback_url = "null";
      var url_scheme = "[URL SCHEME]";
      var loc = window.location;
      function redirect(loc) {
        loc.href = url_scheme;
        if(fallback_url.startsWith("http")) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                loc.href = fallback_url;
            }, 3000)
        }
      }
  </script>
<body onload="redirect(loc)">
         <p>
　　　　　　<a href="#" onclick="redirect(loc)">アプリを開く</a>
        </p>
</body>
```

#### 試したこと

Yahoo メールアプリ側で、外部アプリのURL scheme 、あるいはUniversal Link でのDeeplink が制御されている可能性があります。
全く同じ流れで、他のメールクライアントアプリ（iOS 純正のメールアプリ、Gmail アプリ）では外部アプリにDeeplink できたためです。

※ ただし、"AppStore" アプリは、URL scheme 、Universal Link どちらでもDeeplink できました。
（Music など他の純正アプリは同様の方法でDeeplink できませんでした。）

少しWeb で調べてみたのですが、同様の問題を取り扱っているページが見当たらなかったため、質問するに至りました。
ユーザ登録が必須であるアプリ開発において、認証URL からユーザ登録を行うフローは一般的であるかと思いますので、
同じ問題に直面した経験のある方、あるいは今後この問題に向き合う方のためになればと思います。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/190757

Comment: ATSの設定や、`LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`の記述はどうなっていますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。 URL scheme は `CFBundleURLSchemes` で定義していましたが、 `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` にも記述して、試してみましたが、結果は同じでした。　また、ATS については、WebView を開くのはメールクライアント側なので、私のアプリ側の制御ではなさそうです。

Comment: 追記となりますが、 `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` も、メールクライアント側で設定するべき内容のようです。

Comment: さらに追記ですが、認証URL のドメインは、TLS バージョンなどATS の要求を満たしている状態です。

Comment: よくわからないのですが、`Swift`のタグがついていることからアプリの開発の話ですよね？もし違うのであれば質問文を編集していただき適切なタグと説明になるようにしてください。また、仮にアプリ開発の話であればアプリからCustomURLSchemeを起動する部分について現在記述しているコードを記述してください。

Comment: (やりたい事の)根本的な解決には至っていないのかもしれませんが、Yahoo!からの見解は現時点での「仕様」ということで一つの回答となると思うので、個別の「自己回答」として投稿することを検討してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo 公式から見解をいただきました。
現状ホワイトリストに登録されたもののみ動作する仕様とのことです。

Yahoo メールクライアントを使っているユーザには、認証URL をコピーして、Safari などのブラウザに貼り付けてもらうよう促すようにする必要がありそうです。

**Yahoo! からの回答内容:**

> お問い合わせの「認証URLをYahoo!メールアプリのWebViewで開く場合アプリにDeeplinkできない」件についてご案内いたします。
>
> iOS版Yahoo!メールアプリ内のブラウザーにおいて、他のアプリを起動させるようなURLは、現状ホワイトリストに登録されたもののみが動作する仕様となっております。
>
> お知らせくださいました事象につきましては、現時点でのiOS版Yahoo!メールアプリ側の仕様です。
>
> 恐れ入りますがYahoo!メールアプリ上で、その他の方法で画面を開くことはできません。
>
> 今後、任意のアプリを起動させるURLが全て動作するよう弊社でも対応を検討しておりますが、具体的な対応時期は未定となっております。

---

*この投稿は @MameGO さんが質問に追記されていた内容を、コミュニティwiki の個別の回答として投稿しました。*